# Get first index of any character among array from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have string like this

```
hi, i am not coming today!
```

and i have an array of characters like this:

```
['a','e','i','o','u']
```

now i want to find the first occurrence of any word from array in string.

If it was only word i'd have been able to do it like this:

```
'string'.index 'c'
```

Comment: What do you expect it to return with your given example?

Comment: 1 since "i" is in array and first thing in string

Comment: can you provide the desired output for your example?

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'hi, i am not coming today!'
['a','e','i','o','u'].map { |c| [c, s.index(c)] }.to_h

#⇒ {
#  "a" => 6,
#  "e" => nil,
#  "i" => 1,
#  "o" => 10,
#  "u" => nil
# }
```

To find the first occurence of any character from an array:

```
['a','e','i','o','u'].map { |c| s.index(c) }.compact.min
#⇒ 1
```

**UPD** Something different:

```
idx = str.split('').each_with_index do |c, i| 
  break i if ['a','e','i','o','u'].include? c
end
idx.is_a?(Numeric) ? idx : nil

str =~ /#{['a','e','i','o','u'].join('|')}/

str.index Regexp.union(['a','e','i','o','u']) # credits @steenslag
```

Comment: i want for one character it could be any character from string

Comment: Can you give an example as to why this answer is not correct?

Comment: 2nd edition is correct, i am just waiting to see if someone comes up with something different.

Comment: I added something different :)